# Are Symfony 4 applications stateless?

Tags: symfony, deployment, symfony4, stateless

In order to deploy an application to multiple machines, it's necessary for me to develop a stateless application.

So my question is: is Symfony stateless? Or uses Symfony server variables so that on multiple servers I will have problems?

I have set the stateless option in my security.yml to true:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        stateless: true
```

Is there anything else in Symfony I have to think of in order to create a complete stateless application?

Answer (score 1):

It is always a bit dangerous to generalize but I would suspect that most Symfony apps have server state in the form of sessions.  In particular, if the app requires the user to login then sessions are probably being used.

However, server state does not mean you will have problems with multiple servers.  Session variables can be stored in databases or perhaps redis caches and thus shared.

I have never actually tried using the stateless true option.  Not sure what will happen if you try to use the session.  But it is worth an experiment.  And as long as you don't actually use sessions then your app should be stateless.

And if you do need some kind of state (perhaps to track user login) then there are stateless alternatives to sessions such as [Json Web Tokens(JWT)](https://jwt.io/).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what are you going to use. For example the the database parameters and app_env parameters by the best practices are set as ENS variables on the machine

Answer (score 0):

Symfony doesn't have to be setup to require cookies and sessions, it can equally (though it will take some configuration) use such techniques as JWT's or bearer-tokens.

Equally, it can also be setup to use some form of shared database to hold the information from the session (Redis is very popular for this, and it's what I'm currently using). I've previously used Memcached, but MongoDB and Mysql are also quite possible.